# How to read .txt file

Tags: python, import, text-files

I'm in need of your help. I have a .txt file and I want to print all the texts using Python 2.7.

I've used this code which is shown below. But it is not showing any text except errors.

```
file = open('x.txt' , 'r')
print file.read
```

Now, what to do?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: missing  `(` `)` call read as `read()`

Comment: Wow, I've never seen so many answers that are pretty much exactly the same.

Comment: Also you don't need to put it into read-only mode as Python has that as the default.

Comment: @AlexThornton but no answer explain why OP doesn't get exception.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I think your comment told the OP what was causing the error, and the answers offered optimised fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
file = open('x.txt', 'r')
file_contents = file.read()
print(file_contents)
file.close()
```

Or this:

```
with open('x.txt', 'r') as file:
    file_contents = file.read()
    print(file_contents)
```

Comment: don;t forget to close the file, better to use `with`

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('foo.txt') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'with' will ensure the file is closed.

```
with open('x.txt', 'r') as f:
    print f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Appart from not closing the file when the operations finish i think that the error with your code lies in the path you are providing to the open method

if your filename is indeed "x.txt" then the code below should work:

```
with open("x.txt","r") as f:
    print file.read()
```

If x is a variable name and you intend to replace the contents of x in the path of the file then you should do this:

```
with open("%s.txt"%(str(x)),"r") as f:
    print file.read()
```

Hope that helped!
Cheers,
Alex